# Get string between two same characters vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
ASD~QW~DFGH~LOP~GGGH~123~SXC~QL~
```

I need the string QW,LOP,123,QL which is in between two ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want every 2nd item after splitting on `~`.
This should do that:

```
Dim str = "ASD~QW~DFGH~LOP~GGGH~123~SXC~QL~"
Dim res = str.Split("~"C) _
            .Select(Function(x, i) New with { x, i }) _
            .Where(Function(s) s.i Mod 2 = 1) _
            .Select(Function(s) s.x)
```

Result would be a collection of strings: `"QW","LOP","123","QL"`

Comment: For winforms: `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", res))`

Comment: showing error Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[VB$AnonymousType_2`2[System.String,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.String[]'.

Comment: Updated answer with an additional select to get the string.

Comment: still the message box showing the same error..., i am having framework 3.5

Comment: Perhaps you need a `.ToArray` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, you'll probably want regular expressions.

```
   .*?~([^~]+?)(?=~)
```

Although given your example, String.Split might be massaged into working.

Here's a [ideone sample](http://ideone.com/xTbsTP) of using a regular expression.

And here's a version of the Split function using String.Split....

```
Public Function Split(input As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim results as List(Of String)
    Dim pos = input.IndexOf("~")
    If pos < 0 Then
        Return New List(Of String) ' return empty list if no match
    End If
    input = input.Remove(0, pos)
    input = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf("~"))
    results = input.Split("~").Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList()
    Return results
End Function
```